# Installing Ubuntu alongside windows 8.1

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I have tried to install Ubuntu alongside my windows 8 but when I run the installer, in my bootable flash the installer does not recognize my windows partitions. It shows my hard drive as one unallocated 500GB. I researched and someone had a similar problem and he was instructed to run the following command `sudo fdisk -lu` inside the Ubuntu installer. From his output he was told that some of drives are overlapping. I have run the same command in my installer and this is my output:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x55f36f79

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848   103118847    51200000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       103118848   185038847    40960000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       185038848   976771071   395866112    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       185040896   976771071   395865088    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I have used this same Ubuntu installer on my friends machine and it works well. I have even tried to install mint from a DVD and i get the same problem.
When I run the command above in both installers I get the same output.
When I run another command `sudo gparted -l` i get the following output.

```
Warning: /dev/sda contains GPT signatures
```

indicating that it has a GPT table.
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.
Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT
partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an
msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
Yes/No?

Answer (score 0):

You have GPT disk there are a lot of solutions you can find within this forum no need to create new topic. Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) and read it.

Comment: On the contrary, any on-topic question that is not represented in the Stack Exchange Network is welcome to be added to the network.  In fact, that is the goal.  From the [tour]: "_With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Ubuntu._". Furthermore, all resolving advice is ideally hard-written into answers.  Stack Exchange does not encourage "link-only answers" because they can break or die; this means curators will need to resurrect content with the wayback machine -- this isn't a fun job.