# "no detected operating systems" after partitioning to install Ubuntu alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I'm currently running Windows 7 and decided to dual-boot with Ubuntu. I made a different partition (by referring to a tutorial).

The disk management window looks like:
[image]

Once I boot it from my optical drive, it says:

[image]

I can't see an option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows so I thought of trying to make it manually. The problem is that it doesn't recognize either the unallocated free space or the Windows partition space.

[image]

What should I do?

Edit: I have seen the link in [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/412653/955434) to "Installing Ubuntu alongside windows 8.1", but it is quite complicated and I'm not very experienced at partitioning.

Comment: similar question http://askubuntu.com/questions/412648/installing-ubuntu-alongside-windows-8-1

Comment: Answer to that question is quite complicated as Im not a professional in partinioning.

Comment: Hi! Could you please post a screen after selecting the last option, which is **Something else**.

Comment: Could you please have a look at [**How to install linux on a computer with GPT?**](http://askubuntu.com/a/244334/179042) & try whether it helps!

Comment: Ok so I downloaded it and like it said "Just run it, tell it to delete the stray GPT data when prompted, and exit". What command should I use? As it the program says: Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit:

Comment: Are you running this on windows platform or ubuntu??

Comment: Im running on windows

Comment: Refer to the official [GPT fdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk) website.. It has a [tutorial](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html) on how to achieve this.

Comment: I don't know if Im blind but it doesn't say anything about commands all it says - consult with....

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply install Ubnutu on a GUID Parted Table that is GPT in short which is commonly used by Windows 7, 8... If you want to install Ubuntu on a GPT disk (you can check it via the `sudo parted -l` command), you will need either an EFI partition (if your BIOS is setup in EFI mode) or a BIOS-Boot partition (if your BIOS is setup in Legacy mode). How to create a boot partition provided in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) documentation.

Comment: Ok, can you explain how do I do it? Im like a noob.. :D I guess installing on a GPT disk is a more secure way without losing any data. Anyways, as you said, I've tried to check it via the sudo parted -1. As I understood I needed to type it in the Terminal. However, CTRL+ALT+T does not bring it...

Comment: it doesn't matter in secure ways on a non-GPT is much easier to install it. During installation choose try Ubuntu and after it loads you must able to run Terminal Ctrl+Alt+T or try Alt+F2, F1 if it won't start but it's should start, notice system will be a little more slower in test mode.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried it and here what it says http://imgur.com/cNXlxCt After this I rebooted and nothing has changed. :/

Comment: it's `sudo parted -l` not "-1"

Comment: wow... such fail. gonna try again.. :D

Comment: ... It didn't work too.. After i typed it I rebooted and still nothing changed. Here what it says: http://imgur.com/z954ifd

Comment: no it worked indeed and it says that is GPT table. Take a look at this http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/BIOS-installation.html I'll try to provide you with a bit easier steps yet, I'm thinking.

Comment: Ahmm that seems a bit complicated though If I reread it couple times somehow it would become clear. As one person refered http://askubuntu.com/questions/244329/how-to-install-linux-on-a-computer-with-gpt/244334#244334 What are your thoughts about this one? I think it would be more easier to fix, however i don't know the exact commands. Still trying to figure it out though...

Comment: try this one https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition?action=show&redirect=CreateBootPartition I guess it shows evrything by step.

Comment: @JohnyD. the problem is that he is unable to see any partition --- I was not able to find an easy step-by-step procedure explained. (I added the screenshot to the question, hoping to make it more useful).

Comment: @Rmano I see that but still tried to provide a solution even though indeed it's not that easy.

Comment: Ok, I found a minor error. As i moved to the 4th step. It said  create 1GB (=1000MiB) of free space at the start of the disk where Ubuntu is installed... AS I'm running on windows I still don't have ubuntu installed. So if I was to create new partinion it warned me that I may lose data. (It still said 700gb left)

Comment: In GParted, create a partition (an unformatted one works fine), then right-click it and select Manage Flags. Check the bios_grub flag, click Close, and apply your changes (some versions of GParted will not allow you to set a flag on an unformatted partition; in this case format the partition to FAT16 then set the bios_grub flag). The reason is you need to see the partitions, it looks like you have 1 partition and everything in it.

Comment: Yes I only have one partinion after downgrading win8. Thanks for your support. Aprecciate it. Will try your method tomorrow :).

Comment: Follow this topic too https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI it's the last what I was able to find to show it more clearly.

Comment: Ok so nothing helped :(. Tried to create a partinion either as it was required but couldnt manage flags, then your way with FAT16, still couldnt do it.. here an image: http://imgur.com/SpsdvTh,exXXNj3 After this also ran boot repair http://imgur.com/SpsdvTh,exXXNj3#1 but it didn't do anything...

Comment: BTW quick question. If i choose to allocate 10GB out of 700GB for ubuntu, does it mean that it will install ubuntu and give me a way to store files on that leftover of 690GB? or Will it install and give me just to use the rest ammount of space that I have chosen to allocate?

Comment: ACTUALLY... found another way to install ubuntu. However, it is installed inside win7 so don't know if it is a good idea. I used wubi to install it. Let me know if it is still the same. Also information about free space would be helpful:)

Comment: yes you can store information on NTFS partition, 10GB is just recommended partition size for Ubuntu OS root "/" usually it's 10-15GB in my answer provided in this conversation there's a link for more detailed info about partitioning. I also see on your screenshot unallocated space, did you try to resize it and create a bios boot partition out of it? the requirements of bios boot partition also provided in my answer.